# steady_clock::now() return type invalid with gcc

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, gcc8

I have the following code:

```
#include <chrono>

struct SteadyTime : std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point {
    using time_point::time_point;

    static SteadyTime now() {
      return clock::now();
    }
};
```

This works well with Visual Studio 2019 but with gcc 8.3 I get the following error:

```
<source>: In static member function 'static SteadyTime SteadyTime::now()':

<source>:7:24: error: could not convert 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::now()' from 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::time_point' {aka 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >'} to 'SteadyTime'

       return clock::now();

              ~~~~~~~~~~^~

Compiler returned: 1
```

This code seems to be standard so what could be wrong?

Comment: You cannot implicitly (or explicitly) convert from a base object to a derived object... Try it without `chrono` or similar, just `struct A : B {};`. (Deriving from non-polymorphic `std` facilities is also usually a design flaw.)

Comment: When compiling with VS, make sure you set conformance mode to Yes (/permissive-).  This makes the compiler more standard compliant (turns off a lot of non-standard extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is essentially this:

```
struct Base
{};

Base getBase();

struct Derived : Base
{
    static Derived get() { return getBase(); }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KZyP99

That doesn't work because the compiler has no idea how to convert a `Base` to a `Derived`. You could add a constructor for `Derived` from `Base` to fix this.

I would question the general design though. Inheriting from `std` facilities is generally a design flaw/weakness. Prefer composition over inheritance (*especially* if the thing you intend to derive from is not polymorphic). Have `SteadyTime` expose a `time_point` member if you need to, or wrap its interface manually. Having and using multiple concrete (i.e. non-abstract) classes in the same inheritance hierarchy quickly leads to chaos like object slicing and other UB, as well as general confusion for users.